# Appending a Paragraph or Textbox to a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, richtextbox

Im new to C# but cannot find details anywhere on how to append a Paragraph or Textbox to a RichTextBox programmatically, if it is possible at all.
My end goal is to have a premade "Code Block" insert at the caret with premade properties.
This is what i have so far

XML:

```
<ToolBar Margin="0,0,0,-40">
    <Menu VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
        <MenuItem Header="+ Insert">
            <MenuItem Header="Speech" Click="speechButton_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Code Block" Click="CodeBlock_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>


 <Grid>
    <Grid>
        <!--<TextBox x:Name="titleTextBox" 
                 Margin="10"
                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedNote.Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>-->
        <RichTextBox x:Name="contentRichTextBox"
                 TextChanged="contentRichTextBox_TextChanged"
                 SelectionChanged="contentRichTextBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
private void CodeBlock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textRange = new TextRange(contentRichTextBox.Selection.Start, contentRichTextBox.Selection.End);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Snow);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Consolas"));
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (double)fontSizeComboBox.SelectedItem);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Block.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0));
}
```

**Edited** added pictures for better under standing. One picture is when you press the click event without selecting text and the other is if you do select text and then click event
[image: Without selecting text]

[image: Pasting into the box]

Comment: Content of the `CodeBlock_Click()` handler doesn't clear enough. Do you want to apply the background color, font attributes to all document or only to a the text of the currently inserted paragraph?

Comment: only to the text if the currently inserted paragraph.
I was hoping to get, if you select text, it would box the content in a rectangle
If you click it with nothing selected, it would display a small paragraph (say a couple of chars long) that when pasted into, it boxes the pasted text

Comment: Do I understand correctly, when no text selected the `CodeBlock_Click()` should insert a new paragraph at the current caret position with **'// code placeholder'** text? If YES what will happen if the caret located inside some paragraph? Does a new created paragraph (containing **'// code placeholder'** text) will split the current paragraph on the caret position?

Comment: hmm good point. I guess the caret will be outside the box and when the box is clicked on. the '// Code placeholder' will disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add different kind of [blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ms600208(v=vs.95)?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to the `Document` of the `RichTextBox`:

```
private void CodeBlock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    contentRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("text")));

    var textRange = new TextRange(contentRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, contentRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Snow);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Consolas"));
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (double)fontSizeComboBox.SelectedItem);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Block.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0));
}
```